# In docker-compose, can I use environment variable to construct another invironment variable?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose, can I use environment variable to construct another invironment variable?
eg:

```
environment: 
  - HOST: localhost
  - WITH_PORT: ${HOST}:8080 #host read from env variable above
```

If it is possible - then how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: NO**

[docker-compose docs explain this too here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)

`docker-compose` is a fancy way of writing `docker run ...` commands (correct me if I am wrong?). So, a simple test tells me that you can create an environment variable in `docker-compose` using another env variable **only if that variable is present in your development environment**.

So,

```
environment: 
  - HOST: localhost
  - WITH_PORT: ${HOST}:8080 #host read from env variable above
```

Here, `HOST` needs to exist at your environment and not in container environment (which is probably not what you want).

```
~ $ docker run -it -e c=${a} -e a=b ubuntu env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=4f27e057b515
TERM=xterm
c=
a=b
HOME=/root
 ~ $ docker run -it -e c=${PATH} -e a=b ubuntu env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=ba84596bfdf3
TERM=xterm
c=/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/usr/local/munki:/Applications/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin:/Users/username/opt/packages/cassandra/bin:/Users/username/bin
a=b
HOME=/root
```